# appMobi watchPosition getCurrentPosition fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, appmobi

appMobi watchPosition and getCurrentPosition fails, my little GPS icon comes up and goes on, but copying and pasting from the appmobi site taking their exact example, I should get at the least an alert, if not then an error in the console of the debugger to which I am getting neither.

```
var options = {timeout: 10000, maximumAge: 11000, enableHighAccuracy: true };
//This function is called on every iteration of the watch Position command that fails
var fail = function(){
  alert("Geolocation failed. \nPlease enable GPS in Settings.");
};

//This function is called on every iteration of the watchPosition command that is a success
var suc = function(p){
  alert("Moved To: Latitude:" + p.coords.latitude + "Longitude: " + p.coords.longitude;
};

//This command starts watching the geolocation
var geolocationWatchTimer = AppMobi.geolocation.watchPosition(suc,fail,options);

//Call the stopGeolocation function to stop the geolocation watch
var stopGeolocation = function(){
        AppMobi.geolocation.clearWatch(geolocationWatchTimer);
}
```

......

***UPDATE***

Ok, noticed even though using there example the code is broken to a point. It is missing a ) and a ; So with those put in, I am now getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'watchPosition' of undefined`

alright, ***UPDATE AGAIN***

fixed the last issue, but this one has me stumpped, seems that it runs 2 times be for stoping now, I need it to only run the once. How can I get that?

Answer (score 0):

Put a flag to run only one time.:

```
    ...lat=0;
var suc = function(p){
    if ((p.coords.latitude != undefined)&&(lat==0))
    {
            console.log(p.coords.latitude);
            lat=p.coords.latitude;
```

...